# Retrieve container's comparison function given an iterator

Tags: c++, generics, c++11

Given an iterator, is it possible to retrieve/use the correct comparison function for the collection that this iterator refers to?

For example, let's assume I'm writing a generic algorithm:

```
template <class InIt, class T>
void do_something(InIt b, InIt e, T v) { 
    // ...
}
```

Now, let's say I want to do something simple, like find `v` in `[b..e)`. If `b` and `e` are iterators over a `std::vector`, I can simply use `if (*b == v) ...`. Let's assume, however, that `b` and `e` are iterators over a `std::map`. In this case, I *should* only compare the *keys*, not the whole value type of what's contained in the map.

So the question is, given those iterators into the map, how do I retrieve that map's comparison function that will only compare the keys? At the same time, I don't want to blindly assume that I'm working with a `map` either. For example, if the iterators pointed to a `set`, I'd want to use the comparison function defined for that `set`. If they pointed to a `vector` or `deque`, I'd probably have to use `==`, because those containers won't have a comparison function defined.

Oh, almost forgot: I realize that in many cases, a container will only have an equivalent of `operator<` rather than `operator==` for the elements it contains -- I'm perfectly fine with being able to use that.

Comment: No time to write an answer right now, but this might help http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/key_comp. Hmm, not much, though. The tricky part is getting the container.

Comment: I'm confused for your `set` case. The comparator of a `set` needs to be a total-order, which isn't the case for `operator==`.

Comment: Isn't it the same, whether you compare a map entry's key only or the entire entry? [Edit] Never mind, of course it isn't -- you may not have an equality operation on the mapped part.

Comment: The "correct" comparison function probably doesn't exist. You'll probably just have to create a traits class and use that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no standard way to map from an iterator to the underlying container type (if there is such a container at all). You might be able to use some heuristics to try to determine which container, although that will not be simple and probably not guaranteed either.

For example, you can use a metafunction to determine whether the *value_type* is `std::pair<const K, T>`, which is a hint that this could be a `std::map` and after extracting the types `K` and `T` try to use a metafunction to determine whether the type of the iterator and the type of `std::map<K,T,X,Y>::iterator` or `std::map<K,T,X,Y>::const_iterator` match for a particular combination of `X`, `Y`.

In the case of the map that could be sufficient to *determine* (i.e. guess with a high chance of success) that the iterator refers to a `std::map`, but you should note that even if you can use that and even extract the type `X` of the comparator, that is not sufficient to *replicate* the comparator in the general case. While uncommon (and not recommended) comparators can have state, and you would not know which is the particular state of the comparator without having access to the container directly. Also note that there are cases where this type of heuristic will not even help, in some implementations of `std::vector<>` the iterator type is directly a pointer, and in that case you cannot differentiate between an 'iterator' into an array and an iterator into a `std::vector<>` of the same underlying types.

Answer (score 11):

Iterators don't have to be connected to containers, so they don't give you any details about the containers that they aren't necessarily connected to. That's the essential iterator abstraction: iterators delimit sequences, without regard to where the sequence comes from. If you need to know about containers you have to write algorithms that take containers.

Comment: Example: some `string` and `vector` had iterators implemented as bare pointers (taking advantage of the sequential and contiguous underlying buffer).

Comment: Even if you take containers as arguments, you still need to rely on tricks to distinguish a `Sequence` from an `AssociativeContainer`. I suppose it is hard to write an `is_associative_container` that works reliably.

Comment: @pmr: That trait is actually simple if you only want to support standard containers... you just need to determine whether the type is one of `std::map`, `std::multimap`, `std::set`, `std::multiset` (and the unordered versions if you need to support those, although the concept of *comparator* is not that clear there)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately iterators don't always know about the container that contains them (and sometimes they aren't in a standard container at all). Even the `iterator_traits` only have information about the value_type which doesn't specifically tell you how to compare.

Instead, let's draw inspiration from the standard library. All the associative containers (`map`, etc) have their own `find` methods rather than using `std::find`. And if you *do* need to use `std::find` on a such a container, you don't: you use `find_if`.

It sounds like your solution is that for associative containers you need a `do_something_if` that accepts a predicate telling it how to compare the entries.